# Fabric.js missing properties after clone

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using **Fabricjs 3.4**.

I have a fabric object, say `a` with data

[image]

I'm cloning the same to variable `b` along with some additional data

```
a.clone(d => {
  b = d;
}, {additional: 'data'});
```

But `b` now has some properties missing which where in `a`.

[image]

It can be noticed that `x: "14", y: "0"` is missing in `b`.

Comment: The referenced question's answer only shows how to pass additional fields which has to be retained while cloning. In my case, I have only referenced the `x` and `y` but there are bunch others missing and even the nested object like `canvas` in `a` is missing in `b`. In my question, I'm already passing a dictionary of objects to assign `{additional: 'data'}`. How can I pass additional fields along with the additional object?

Comment: Passing array with the keys instead of the dictionary object solved the issue.

Comment: You should extent all custom properties after clone funciton like this : `var clone = fabric.util.object.clone(activeObject)`
` clone.toObject = (function (toObject) {
                            return function () {
                                return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {x: 10, y: 10});
                            };
                        })(clone.toObject);`